# How to pass an onMouseEnter function into child component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to update my parent component's state when hovering over a child component. Basically, this parent component consists of an `h1` and four components called `Box`. Each component has a `title` prop, which the component renders internally. What I would like to have happen is when a user hovers over a `Box`, the `hovered` state of the parent component changes to the `title` of the hovered child. Here is essentially what I have right now:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {
   hovered: 'none'
 };
 this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this);
}

handleHover = (n) => {
 this.setState((n) => ({
   hovered: n
 }));
};
handleHoverOut = () => {
 this.setState(() => ({
   hovered: 'none'
 }));
};

render() { 
 return (
   <h1 className={this.state.hovered} >TITLE TITLE TITLE</h1>
   <Box oME={ this.handleHover } oML={ this.handleHoverOut } title='Title1'/>
   <Box oME={ this.handleHover } oML={ this.handleHoverOut } title='Title2'/>
   <Box oME={ this.handleHover } oML={ this.handleHoverOut } title='Title3'/>
   <Box oME={ this.handleHover } oML={ this.handleHoverOut } title='Title4'/>
 )
}

class Box extends React.Component {
render() {
 return(
   <section onMouseEnter={() => { this.props.oME(this.props.title)}} onMouseLeave={() => { this.props.oML()}}>
     ...
   </section>
}
```

I know this might not be 100% the way to go about it, but I think I'm somewhat on the right track! Please help me try to improve my code here, since I'm still learning the basics of React!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-babbage-qefq5r?file=/src/App.js:51-1147) where you can check the solution.

There were couple of issues in your code that I fixed there. Your `state` was not being displayed properly as title and there were unneeded `callback` functions.